# como insertar el dato que se muestra en el script a mysql

Tags: javascript, date, label

buenos dias tengo una pregunta como se almacena en mysql la hora que se me aparece en el textbox de th y de paso que también se muestre el TE y se guarde   en una base de datos academ y tabla reporte

```
    <th scope="col"><th scope="col"><p>TM</p>
  <input type="text" name="tiempomuerto" id="tiempomuerto"  value=""/>
  </th>

  <th scope="col"><th scope="col"><p>TE</p><input type="text" name="tiempoefectivo" id="tiempoefectivo"  value=""/>
  </form></th>
</table>


<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="tiempoefectivorHoras();"value="Enviar"  /></p>
```

//Script para que se calcule la Tmñ

```
function tiempoefectivorHoras() {

  horaemision = document.getElementById("horaemision").value;
  horaintervencion = document.getElementById("horaintervencion").value;
   

  
  horaemisionMinutos = parseInt(horaemision.substr(3,2));
  horaemisionHoras = parseInt(horaemision.substr(0,2));
  
  //Hora intervención son valores que toma para que se haga la resta en de numeros
  horaintervencionMinutos = parseInt(horaintervencion.substr(3,2));
  horaintervencionHoras = parseInt(horaintervencion.substr(0,2));
  
//Tiempo en minutos

  transcurridoMinutos = horaintervencionMinutos - horaemisionMinutos;
  transcurridoHoras = horaintervencionHoras - horaemisionHoras;
   
  //Tiempo en horas
  if (transcurridoMinutos < 0) {
    transcurridoHoras--;
    transcurridoMinutos = 60 + transcurridoMinutos;
  }
  //String para que que se muestre la hora correcta
  horas = transcurridoHoras.toString();
  minutos = transcurridoMinutos.toString();
```

//Aquí es para el cálculo de hora con variable

```
  if (horas.length < 2) {
    horas = "0"+horas;
  }
  
  if (horas.length < 2) {
    horas = "0"+horas;
  }
  
  document.getElementById("tiempoefectivo").value = horas+":"+minutos;

}

</script>



</fieldset>
</form>
```

Los cálculos los hace bien pero quisiera que se guarden en la bdd

Comment: Que haz intentado hasta el momento?

Comment: procesa esos datos en el backend, manda los datos como salen en el input, lo que buscas se llama "ajax"

Comment: Tengo ya la conexión tengo la bdd tengo casi todo. Solo me falta la inserción de datos

Answer (score 0):

prueba con la siguiente sintaxis

**Crear la tabla: en mysql**

```sql
CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla(
    id INT(11) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre_campo1 VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    tiempoefectivo TIME
)
```

**Y para guardar un registro puede ocupar la siguiente sintaxis**

```sql
INSERT INTO  nombre_tabla(nombre_campo1, tiempoefectivo) VALUES ('datos', '14:16:18');
```

**Nota:** para que esto sea posible debes de tener un servidor en el backend que haga tal tarea para eso se puede usar cualquier lenguaje de programación: Node.js, java, C#, python etc.